# Devise User Profile link in Navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following code for the nav-bar in my application, using Devise for user authentication.

```
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="">
            <%= link_to root_path do %>
            <i class="icon-home"></i> Home
            <% end %>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <%= link_to current_user do %>
            <i class="icon-book"></i> Portfolio
            <% end %>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <%= link_to help_path do %>
            <i class="icon-question-sign"></i> Help
            <% end %>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <%= link_to(destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete') do %>
            <i class="icon-signout"></i> Logout
            <% end %>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

It works fine on the home page and the user profile page, but when I go to the other pages, such as the Projects or Help page( both of which have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in their controllers ), it throws the following error

```
     NoMethodError in Projects#index 
     undefined method `find_by_remember_token' for #<Class:0x3ec18d0>
```

It says that the offending code is this part:

```
    <%= link_to current_user do %>
```

Which I use to link the user to his/her profile. Any ideas how to fix this error?

Update:
It seems like the problem solved itself after adding

```
    @user = current_user
```

to the page's respective controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if user signed in.

```
<%= link_to if_user_signed_in?, current_user %>
```

Comment: ```current_used=current_user```

Comment: It still outputs the same error. I've also tried putting the whole navbar inside an `if user_signed_in?` clause to no avail.